# How to mock ServiceBusClient

Tags: c#, azure, mocking

I have the next method, notice that I'm doing `new ServiceBusClient(connectionString)`, I'd like i could mock this so it throws a desire exception. I'm using NSubstitute, but I have no idea how I could do this.

```cs
 public void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                switch (exception)
                {
                    case FormatException _:
                        logger.LogError(new ConnectionStringFormatError(connectionString));
                        break;
                    case ServiceBusException _:
                        logger.LogError(new ConnectionError(exception.Message));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

ServiceBusClient's constructor has parameters, so I can't mock the class itself. Is there any approch to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make this code testable, and mock `ServiceBusClient`, you should not use it directly in your code, but via abstraction.

So first create abstraction of the factory, which will create service bus client for you. Something like this:

```
public interface IServiceBusClientFactory
{
   ServiceBusClient GetServiceBusClient();
}
```

Then you need implementation of this abstraction. And implementation of this abstraction will create instance of `ServiceBusClient`

```
public class ServiceBusClientFactory : IServiceBusClientFactory
{
    private readonly string _connStr;


    public ServiceBusClientFactory(string connStr)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connStr))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connStr));
        }

        _connStr = connStr;
    }

    public ServiceBusClient GetServiceBusClient()
    {
        return new ServiceBusClient(_connStr);
    }
}
```

Then your client code will use `IServiceBusClientFactory` interface, and you could mock it in unit test as much as you like.

```
var clientMock = Substitute.For<IServiceBusClientFactory>();
clientMock.GetServiceBusClient(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => throw new FormatExcepction());
```

Of course, this requires usage of IoC - then you'll benefit from abstractions usage.